# Pathname expansion inside brace expansion

Tags: linux, bash, brace-expansion

The following code is working:

```
mkdir /home/karan/{Pictures,Public}/yo
```

The above line creates a `yo` named directory in the directories named `Public` and `Pictures`. However when I use the below code I get an error:

```
mkdir /home/karan/{P*}/yo
error: cannot create directory ‘/home/karan/{P*}/123’
```

I know that the asterisk is not expanding into the given directories but cannot understand the reason. I also haven't used any quoting mechanisms to suppress the asterisk expansion.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`, you can do:

```
(){ mkdir $^@/yo; } /home/karan/P*(/)
```

(where `$^array` turns on `rcexpandparam` (for `rc`-style array expansion) for the expansion of `$array` only, and the expansion of that glob (here with a `/` glob qualifier to restrict to files of type *directory*) is turned into the `$@` array through the use of an anonymous function).

Or you could do:

```
mkdir /home/karan/P*(/e:REPLY+=/yo:)
```

(using the `e`valuate glob qualifier to append a `/yo` to matching files).

Or:

```
set -o histsubstpattern
mkdir /home/karan/P*(/:s:%:/yo)
```

(using the `:s/string/replacement/` csh-style modifier to add `/yo` in that case. With `histsubstpattern`, the `string` is interpreted as a pattern and like in ksh's `${var/pattern/replacement}`, a leading `%` means the pattern is anchored at the end of the subject)

With `rc` or derivatives:

```
dirs = ( /home/karan/P*/ )
mkdir $dirs^yo
```

`es`, one of those `rc` derivatives also has anonymous functions like `zsh` above, though with a different syntax:

```
@ {mkdir $*^yo} /home/karan/P*/
```

With `fish`:

```
set dirs /home/karan/P*/
mkdir ${dirs}yo
```

With ksh93 or bash (or zsh), you could always do:

```
dirs=(/home/karan/P*/)
mkdir "${dirs[@]/%/yo}"
```

Or with any shell and GNU `xargs`:

```
printf '%syo\0' /home/karan/P*/ | xargs -r0 mkdir
```

(beware that the expansion of `P*/` (as opposed to `zsh`'s `P*(/)`) would also include symlink to directories. In `zsh`, replace the `/` glob qualifier with `-/` if its actually what you want).

Comment: I would expect `mkdir "${dirs[@]/%/yo}"` to trigger `${parameter/pattern/replacement}`. Doesn't it?

Comment: @Quasimodo, yes and if the pattern starts with `%`, that anchors it at the end of the subject. When applied to `array[@]`, that applies to all elements of the array.

Answer (score 1):

[Bash's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

> Patterns to be brace expanded take the form of an optional preamble, followed by either a series of comma-separated strings or a sequence expression between a pair of braces

Your attempt

1. ```
   mkdir /home/karan/{P*}/123
   ```

is not a valid form of brace expansion, since there are no commas nor a sequence inside the braces.
Thus, you get exactly what you have given, `/home/karan/{P*}/123`.

2. ```
   mkdir /home/karan/{P*,}/123
   ```

is a brace expansion (note the comma) which would try to create `/home/karan/P*/123` and `/home/karan//123` directories.
Note that still `P*` is not expanded with filename expansion, because there are yet no `.../Pictures/123` and `.../Public/123` directories. In other words, when there is no match, filename expension does not happen.

Anyway, as (1) shows, it does not make sense to use a brace expansion with a single element, it is like a seesaw with a single person. The direct

3. ```
   mkdir /home/karan/P*/123
   ```

would fail for the same reason, no match.

I don't see a nice way to escape spelling the paths out in your particular case, but if there are many matching directories or paths, a for loop will save you keystrokes.

```
for d in /home/karan/P*/; do mkdir "$d"yo; done
```

Comment: "it is like a seesaw with a single person" what a sad image.

Comment: @glennjackman I thought a carriage without horses could suggest a subordinate relation so I ditched it. I need to improve my analogies repertoire.

Comment: Related - [Filename pattern for files that don't yet exist](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/395302/100397)